# Create an instance of derived class from the base class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, instantiation

I have my abstract base class **A**:

```
public abstract class A : ICloneable {

    public int Min { get; protected set; }
    public int Max { get; protected set; }

    public A(int low, int high)
    {
        this.Min = low;
        this.Max = high;
    }

    //...

    public object Clone()
    {
        return new this(this.Min, this.Max); //<-- ??
    }
}
```

Which is extended by my class **B**:

```
public class B : A
{
    public B(int low, int high) : base(low, high) { }

    //...
}
```

Since **A** is abstract, it cannot be instantiated, but the derived class can.
Is it possible to, from class **A**, create a new instance of class **B**?

Suppose class **A** has many derived classes, how will it know which one to instantiate?

Well, I want to instantiate the same class (or type) my currently **A** is.

That is, if I'm calling the `Clone` method from a class **B**, I want to instantiate a new **B**.
If I'm calling the `Clone` method from a class **C**, I want to instantiate a new **C**.

My approach was to write something like:

```
return new this(this.Min, this.Max);
```

But that doesn't seem to work nor compile.

Is it possible to accomplish this in **C#**?

If it isn't, is there an explanation so I can understand?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but why are you not using this.MemberwiseClone() instead ?

Comment: I was not aware of a MemberwiseClone() method, but I just want the copy to be a new instance, with the same constructor arguments. Any other processing MemberwiseClone may do would be useless

Comment: What if `B` construtor adds one more parameter?

Comment: I hope that doesn't happen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I like Jamiec solution, I'm missing dirty solution using reflection :)

```
public class A {
  public object Clone() {
    var type = GetType().GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) });
    return type.Invoke(new object[] { this.Min, this.Max });
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the obvious reflection solution that works with non-parameterless ctors

Comment: Ohhhh dirty, I like it :D

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is possible with an abstract factory method on your base class

```
public abstract class A
{
   public int Min { get; protected set; }
   public int Max { get; protected set; }

   public A(int low, int high)
   {
       this.Min = low;
       this.Max = high;
   }
   protected abstract A CreateInstance(int low, int high);

   public object Clone()
   {
      return this.CreateInstance(this.Min,this.Max);
   }
}

public class B:A
{
   public B(int low, int high)
      : base(low,high)
   {
   }
   protected override A CreateInstance(int low, int high)
   {
      return new B(low,high);     
   }
}
```

Comment: This solution crossed my mind too, but I was looking forward to not adding construction code in each derived class, but let C# do it for me, instantiating whatever derived class is being used to extend A. I hope I'm explaining myself well enough

Comment: @MatiCicero - that's doable but you're going to be dabbling in a lot of reflection. Consider if this is the right solution for you

Comment: I'll test both answers and come back with a conclusion. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This can be done and your current approach is a well defined design pattern, though most implementations make the `Clone` an abstract virtual method and override it in all subclasses.

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract A Clone( );
}

public class B : A
{
    public override A Clone( )
    {
        return new B( );
    }
}

public class C : A
{
    public override A Clone( )
    {
        return new C( );
    }
}
```

Since you are using C# you could make use of the `Activator` class.  You can make the `Clone` method virtual (not === abstract) with a default implementation of.

```
public abstract class A
{
    public virtual A Clone( )
    {
        // assuming your derived class contain a default constructor.
        return (A)Activator.CreateInstance(this.GetType( ));
    }
}
```

**Edit -**
If you do not have a default parameter-less constructor in all of your derived classes, you can add parameters to the `Activator.CreateInstance` method

```
(A)Activator.CreateInstance(this.GetType( ), this.Min, this.Max);
```

For varying constructors on the derived types I would recommend you override the `Clone` method specifically for those types instead of using the default implementation of `Clone`.

Comment: That last example will have to cast the response to `A` as in `return (A)Activator.CreateInstance(this.GetType( ));` as Activator.CreateInstance returns object

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, I will test it and come back with news

Comment: The problem with this solution is it relies on a parameterless constructor, which the OP does not have. For reflection solution that works with your constructor look at the other answer @MatiCicero

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from adding parameters to the `Activator.CreateInstance` method.  I chose to omit them because derived class constructors are unknown within the scope of A (see edit for continuation..)