# How can I create an instance of a derived class from an instance of a base class and include private fields?

Tags: c#, inheritance

My question is kind of related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163478/create-an-instance-of-derived-class-from-the-base-class) but a bit more specific.

I have a domain object `Customer` that looks like this:

```
public class Customer : Party
{
    public Identity Identity {get; protected set;}
    public bool IsOrganization {get; set;}
}
```

and Identity looks like this:

```
public class Identity : PersistableModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public string LegalName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSynchronized { get; private set; }
}

public abstract class PersistableModel : IPersistableModel
{
    public const long UnassignedId = 0;
    public static readonly DateTime MinimumDateTime = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);

    private readonly List<string> modifiedProperties = new List<string>();
    public virtual ModelState State { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> ModifiedProperties { get { return modifiedProperties; } }
    protected bool HasModifiedProperties { get { return 0 < modifiedProperties.Count; } }
    public bool WasModified(string propertyName)
    {
        return modifiedProperties.Contains(propertyName);
    }
    public void WasModified(string propertyName, bool modified)
    {
        if (modified)
        {
            if (!WasModified(propertyName)) modifiedProperties.Add(propertyName);
        }
        else 
        {
            modifiedProperties.Remove(propertyName);
        }
    }

    public virtual void OnPersisting()
    {
    }

    public abstract void Accept(Breadcrumb breadcrumb, IModelVisitor visitor);
}
```

Now based on the value of IsOrganization some logic within Identity needs to change, specifically if IsOrganization is true the Individual related fields (first name, last name, etc...) need to return null and when it is false the Organization fields need to return null.

Previously this was done by having different implementations of the customer that would initialize the identity to different base class in their constructors however the change I'm working on needs to remove the class separation of these two customer types.

What I was thinking is for the Identity property to look something like this:

```
public override Identity Identity
{
    get
    {
         if (IsOrganization)
         {
             return OrgnaizationIdentity.FromIdentity(base.Identity);
         }
         else
         {
             return IndividualIdentity.FromIdentity(base.Identity);
         }
     } 
 }
```

and the From Identity method looks like this:

```
public static OrgnaizationIdentity FromIdentity(Identity identity)
{
    return new OrgnaizationIdentity
    {
        FirstName = identity.FirstName,
        LastName = identity.LastName,
        MiddleNameInitial = identity.MiddleNameInitial,
        Title = identity.Title
    };
}
```

The problem here is the original identity object has some private fields that need to be returned as well.

So my question is, is there an accepted way of doing something like this?

Comment: If you need to expose those fields, can't you make them public in `Identity`? Or is it not yours (external)?

Comment: I've added the Identity code as well,  they are all already public. What I need to override some of the the fields to return null based on the (currently) the subtype of Identity.

Comment: have you already thought about a NULLIdentity class based upon your Identity Class? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

Comment: @Infer-On That is how the original setup worked, for example OrganizationIdentity overrode the Individual fields and returned null instead of the value. I can't find a away to re-implement that with the new form of the customer.

Comment: The question has little to do with the title.

Comment: And is there a compelling reason for this value-based DIY inheritance or could you alter the model? It looks very contrived.

Comment: @HenkHolterman how so, the title explains exactly what I'm trying to do. If you could suggest a change to either the title or the question that would be appreciated.

Comment: What @HenkHolterman tries to say is that there are no private fields in the Identity class to return, while the title mentions something about them.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The model is being used to create an xml output so model alterations have to be small, and the original design was poor and didn't account for a customer being changed from business to individual and vice versa so I'm trying to undo that bad design.

Comment: @MarcelN Oh ok that makes sense, my apologies i'm deeply editing the code as it is a proprietary system and trying to not miss anything important, I will see what I can do to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Copy constructor can do this, if you can add and use one:

```
class Identity
{
    private int x;
    public Identity(Identity that)
    {
        this.x = that.x;
    }
}

class OrgnaizationIdentity : Identity 
{
    public OrgnaizationIdentity(Identity that) : base(that) { ... }
}
```

Comment: I like it, I'll have to implement that a few times due to a rather deep inheritance chain but its the cleanest method I've seen.

Comment: yeah, I like it also now that the my understanding of your objects has sunk in

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you wouldn't just mark the attribs as `public` or even `protected` if these are truly subclassed (i'm guess they are), but here is a hack around it.

Why not create `static` factory methods on the `Identity` class?  That way you have access to private members of the Identity?  It seems to me you are implementing the anti pattern known as the 'Anemic data model' by having other classes responsible for the creation of another business object.

Why couldn't you add something like this to your Identity class:

```
public static Identity CreateIdentity(Customer from)
{
     Identity newId = null;
     //call other factory....
     if (from.IsOrganization)
     {
         newId =  OrgnaizationIdentity.FromIdentity(from);
     }
     else
     {
         newId = IndividualIdentity.FromIdentity(from);
     }

     //populate Identity private attribs here...
}
```

This allows the other factory methods to create the subclasses... but allows the `Identity` factory to see the private vars...

Comment: That is essentially what I tried, however I don't have access to the private fields in order to create the new derived class

Comment: Unfortunately the identity class has no knowledge of the IsOrganization flag, that is only known at the customer level, and as these models are used to generate xml I can't be moving things around too much. So I would need two factory methods on the Identity class, whcih by all means I could do it just feels dirty :)

Comment: well you could send an attribute or even a delegate callback for the initial creation and allow the new factory to set the privates...