# How can I initialize an instance of a derived class from an instance of the base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I've looked at [How can I create an instance of a derived class from an instance of a base class and include private fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269824/how-can-i-create-an-instance-of-a-derived-class-from-an-instance-of-a-base-class) and [Create an instance of derived class from the base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163478/create-an-instance-of-derived-class-from-the-base-class) but either I'm not getting it, or they're not quite what I'm looking for.

I have a class, derived from another, also implementing a particular interface:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass, IDerivedClass
```

`BaseClass` implements `IBaseClass` and `IDerivedClass` inherits `IBaseClass`.

Sometimes, I want to be able to initialize the derived class, when I already have an instance of the base class. I could create a constructor that simply copies each of the properties from the instance of the base to the properties of the instance of the derived class, but is there another way? Something along the lines of:

```
BaseClass bc = new BaseClass();
DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass() : bc;
```

Is this do-able? If not, why not? I'm prepared to accept that it might not be possible, but if so, I'd be quite interested if anyone can explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

You have to create another object since it has to have the characteristics of the second object. You can't just copy one into another. You might up with an object with an invalid state if this was allowed.

The best thing to do is create a 'copy constructor', as you already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported by the language.
The best you can do is write a generic copy method yourself inside `BaseClass`

```
public T Copy<T>()
    where T : BaseClass, new()
{
    var copy = new T();
    // set all properties
    return T;
}
```

Comment: This won't work since you cannot set the properties of the derived class when you do not know the `T`. In other words, in this method you can only set the properties of the base class.